# @polyvar not defined, when using MultivariatePolynomials

Tags: julia, polynomials

When trying to compile the code below (Which is from [here](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1ASfjB1TdLJmYxT0b6rnyGh9eLbMc-66bTOt3_3yvc90/edit#slide=id.g1f502a466d_1_56)), I am told " @polyvar is not defined". I am using Julia v.0.6

```
using MultivariatePolynomials
@polyvar(x[1:2])
p = 2x[1] + 3x[1]x[2]^2 + x[2] + 3
differentiate(p, x[1])
p([1,2], x)
```

Message: UndefVarError: @polyvar not defined.

Please, what would be wrong?

Comment: works fine for me... does the package load correctly?

Comment: Sorry, still not working! Same versioninfo() like you. I even tried to run the following: Pkg.rm("MultivariatePolynomials"), readdir(Pkg.dir()), Pkg.add(MultivariatePolynomials) Pkg.update(), without success. Please, where could the problem be? By the way, trying to circumvent the above issue: Is TypedPolynomials or [DynamicPlynomials] (https://github.com/blegat/DynamicPolynomials.jl) implementable yet? I ran Pkg.add("DynamicPlynomials"), Output: unknown package DynamicPolynomials.

Comment: Is that a copy past of what you typed? Because it would be `Pkg.add("MultivariatePolynomials.jl")` (use backticks for code in comments) what's the output when you add the package?

Comment: Thanks Alexander. When typing `Pkg.add("MultivariatePolynomials.jl")`, I receive: **INFO: Package MultivariatePolynomials is already installed**. But still the code does not work.

Comment: Weird ... What's the output of `include("$(Pkg.dir())/MultivariatePolynomials/src/MultivariatePolynomials.jl")`

Comment: This is the output: **MultivariatePolynomials**, accompanied with the following warning message *WARNING: Compat.AsyncCondition is deprecated, use Base.AsyncCondition instead.
  likely near C:\Users\s1364322\.julia\v0.6\IJulia\src\kernel.jl:31
WARNING: Compat.AsyncCondition is deprecated, use Base.AsyncCondition instead.
  likely near C:\Users\s1364322\.julia\v0.6\IJulia\src\kernel.jl:31*

Comment: and then `MulivariatePolynomials.@polyvar`?

Comment: This is the output of `MulivariatePolynomials.@polyvar`: UndefVarError: MulivariatePolynomials not defined

Comment: in the same session as you `include`d the module it tells you its not defined?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may have been recent changes in the package, and now it seems `@polyvar` is defined in TypedPolynomials package, and MultivariatePolynomials defines a common interface for which TypedPolynomials is an implementation. So,

```
# install TypedPolynomials
Pkg.clone("https://github.com/rdeits/TypedPolynomials.jl")

using MultivariatePolynomials
using TypedPolynomials
```

should clear the problem:

```
julia> @polyvar(x[1:2])
(x1, x2)
julia> p = 2x[1] + 3x[1]x[2]^2 + x[2] + 3
3x1x2^2 + 2x1 + x2 + 3
```

And you would like to change the last line to:

```
julia> p(x=>[1,2])
19
```

Comment: Just to precise that for functions like `differentiate(p, x[1])`, `subs(p, x[1]=>2, x[2]=>3)`, and `...`, we need to run `using MultivariatePolynomials` besides `using TypedPolynomials`